# Translating and adding a language to Android 'Language & input' menu

Tags: android, localization, locale, translate

I would be really grateful if anyone could help me out on this.

I've put a lot of time into translating the main Strings.xml files (e.g the ones found in packages/apps/Settings/res/values) into Welsh. I've tested them by replacing the Strings.xml file in the values-en-rGB folder. The next step (which I am really stuck on) is having Welsh appear as an option in the 'Language & input' menu.

I've created a values-cy-rGB folder according the the ISO naming convention, but I can't find where I should associate this with Welsh (Cymraeg). I would have thought there would be a reference somewhere which lists which languages appear in the menu and points the system towards the correct folder extensions? I've read up on locales but I can't seem to find any info on translating the Android system itself; only info on translating apps.

I'm compiling KitKat 4.4.2 r_1 on ubuntu and testing using the emulator.

Many thanks

Sion

Comment: The reason you're not finding a lot of info is that this has to be built into the ROM, you don't generally add locales afterwards.  And OEMs generally lock a phone to a set of locales for a region.  This site http://udhyantimilsina.wordpress.com/2013/08/15/how-to-unlock-developer-mode-to-set-multiple-languages-on-android-os-4-2-2/ has some explanations on how to do it after the fact, but it may not work for all locales.  Welsh is kind of an obscure one.

Comment: Thanks Gabe, that page does look interesting. I am actually making modifications at the ROM level, I'm able to substitute the strings.xml file in the values-en-rGB folder for my translated versions, which means the system effectively becomes Welsh language when English (United Kingdom) is selected in the 'Language & input' menu. The issue is that I can't for the life of me figure out how to have Welsh listed as a separate option in that language & input menu alongside all of the other languages. Do you know how they lock a phone to a subset of language? Thanks, Sion